# Can you have a fallback option when GitHub self hosted runner is unavailable?

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm currently using a self hosted runner for CI purposes. The issue is that if the self hosted runner is not available for some reason, and is not accessible for the time being, the action will hang forever until the self hosted runner comes back online.

I was wondering if it would be possible to fall back to a shared runner when a self-hosted runner is not available.

Comment: Seems like a Feature Request is open for this https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/20019

Comment: The feature request above still remains unanswered as of March 2024